# PostgreSQL How to merge two tables row to row without condition

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables
The first table contains three text fields(username, email, num) the second have only one column with random birth_date DATE.
I need to merge tables without condition
For example
first table:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| username |    email     |    num    |
+----------+--------------+-----------+
| 'user1'  | 'user1@mail' | '+794949' |
| 'user2'  | 'user2@mail' | '+799999' |
+----------+--------------+-----------+
```

second table:

```
+--------------+
|  birth_date  |
+--------------+
| '2001-01-01' |
| '2002-02-02' |
+--------------+
```

And I need result like

```
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| username |   email    |     num     |  birth_date  |
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 'user1'  | 'us1@mail' | '+7979797'  | '2001-01-01' |
| 'user2'  | 'us2@mail' | '+79898998' | '2002-02-02' |
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I need to get in result table with 100 rows too
Tried different JOIN but there is no condition here

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is a join condition, about the simplest there is: `Join on true` or `cross join`. Either is the basic *merge tables without condition*. However this does not result in what you want as it generates a result set of 10k rows. But you an then use  `limit`:

```
select * 
  from table1 
  join table2 on true 
  order by random()
  limit 100;

select * 
  from table1 
  cross join table2
  order by random()
  limit 100;
```

There is other option, witch I think may be closer to what you want.  Assign a value to each row of each table. Then join on this assigned value:

```
select <column list>
  from (select *, row_number() over() rn from table1) t1 
  join (select *, row_number() over() rn from table2) t2
    on (t1.rn = t2.rn);
```

To eliminate the assigned value you must specifically list each column desired in the result. But that is the way it should be done anyway.

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aTA_cgMz). (demo user just 3 rows instead of 100)

Comment: Thank u alote!
And  mini question
I have function that give me one random date in range
What best way to add this for every row from my table users

Comment: Just add the function call to the select statement. `select t.*, function_giving_1_date() as random_date from table t`.